# QGIS 2.4 Processing (Zonal Statistics) error

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, zonal-statistics, qgis-2.4

In QGis 2.2 all my models (processing model builder) are working fine. When I start the same models in 2.4 I get errors like this:

> Prepare algorithm 5: Zonal Statistics
>   Running Zonal Statistics [6/8]
>   Parameters: RASTERLAYER_RASTER =C:\Temp\processing\779310258f5d4cc5a0d3f0c747b2627f\RESULT.tif, VECTORLAYER_GRENZEN =C:/Tempordner_GIS/ASL_EK/Bereinigt/018-01/DGM5_UTM32_6stell.shp
>   Prepare algorithm 0: Zonal Statistics
>   Running Zonal Statistics [1/1]
>   Parameters: INPUT_RASTER =C:\Temp\processing\779310258f5d4cc5a0d3f0c747b2627f\RESULT.tif, RASTER_BAND =1, INPUT_VECTOR =C:/Tempordner_GIS/ASL_EK/Bereinigt/018-01/DGM5_UTM32_6stell.shp, COLUMN_PREFIX =_, GLOBAL_EXTENT =True
>   Failed
>   Failed
>   Error executing algorithm 5 Error executing algorithm 0 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'GetGeoTransform' See log for more details

This is the error log:

> Uncaught error while executing algorithm
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISCH~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\core\GeoAlgorithm.py", line 217, in execute
>       self.processAlgorithm(progress)
>     File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISCH~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\qgis\ZonalStatistics.py", line 78, in processAlgorithm
>       geoTransform = rasterDS.GetGeoTransform()
>   AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'GetGeoTransform'

Has anyone a tip for me?

Comment: Could you not re-create your models in QGIS 2.4? Also, do you have both QGIS 2.2 and 2.4 installed? I'm only guessing that there might be a conflict issue...?

Comment: When I re-create them it obviously works! But this would be a lot of work.

Comment: In QGIS 2.4, there may have been changes to the core plugins code which could differ from QGIS 2.2. Perhaps you can save your model from 2.2 as a Python script, load the script into 2.4 and run it **as a script**. You will be told on which line the error(s) is which might make it easier to debug (if you know a little Python). But hopefully someone could provide much more helpful advice than me :)

Comment: Thanx for the tip. I have never worked with python scripts. Is it easy to re -import the model (I saved it as a python script)?

Comment: _Processing Toolbox_ > _Scripts_ > _Tools_, you can either add the script from file or very simply copy/paste into a new script. Remember to save it in C:\Users\(_your user name_)\.qgis2\processing\scripts (this is the directory for 2.2, not sure if 2.4 uses the same)

Comment: I checked all my models again I I gues there might be a problem with the processing-modeler and the zonal statistics tool. It works fine when I use it outside the modeler. Could anyone check this again?

Comment: When you use QGIS 2.4 be sure that you don't have any "processing" folder inside

.qgis2/python/plugins
If you have it, then delete it (it is an obsolete version of processing compared to the one shipped with qgis 2.4/master). After that close QGIS, reopen it and try again.